# Shadow whole page behind ui-panel in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I got the following code:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="exercises-page" data-url="exercises-page">

         <a href="#left-panel" id="menu-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

         <div data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" id="left-panel" data-theme="b" data-position-fixed="true" data-position="left">
              content
         </div>

    </div>
```

Which pretty much gives me a blank page with a button that opens up the side menu. The panel has a small `box-shadow` by default which I would like to replace with a full shadow/dark overlay on everything that is behind the panel while the panel is open.

Does someone know how this can be done?

Comment: Where's your CSS? You should post the entire relevant extracts of your HTML, CSS & JS as a Snippet or Fiddle so we can see what's happening now and what needs to be changed.

Comment: I haven't made any changes yet, everything is by default. I added the piece of HTML code that I made, CSS/JS is imported from jQuery Mobile.

Comment: add `background` color to `.ui-panel-dimiss` this is in case the panel is dismissible. You can animate it too. https://jsfiddle.net/uxrwgrxu/

Comment: @Omar That worked, thanks! Do you know if there is any way to display the background color after the sidepanel is fully slided since it looks strange now due to the blank space between the shadow and the slider while it's sliding?

Comment: You'll need some JS https://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/y393ykgc/

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help!

Comment: Another option: https://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/y393ykgc/